# How to specify compare/key method for sorting method in R?

Tags: r, sorting

In Python you can use the key=... to specify the key used to compare items when sorting.
Is there a similar way to do this in R ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me extend the excellent answer of Richie.

If you want to get the order of any key, `order` is the function you're looking at. Building on Richie's example :

```
id <- order(tolower(x))
x[id] # gives you the original ordered vector
```

If you want specific keys, you have to take a look at ordered factors. Say you want to order observations following the series small, bigger, biggest.

We create a dataframe :

```
x <- data.frame(V1=1:10,
        V2=sample(c("small","bigger","biggest"),10,TRUE)
     )
```

Now you can order this using:

```
id <- order(ordered(x$V2,levels=c("small","bigger","biggest")))
x[id,]
```

the function `ordered()` makes the factor x$V2 an ordered factor according to the levels you specify. `order()` gives you the order of this ordered vector. That order you can use to sort the dataframe `x`.

If you want to sort first on V2 and then on V1, you can give multiple arguments to order as well :

```
id <- order(ordered(x$V2,levels=c("small","bigger","biggest")),x$V1)
x[id,]
```

Regarding your question: You don't need lambda expressions for that, as Richie showed. By the `x[order(tolower(x))]` you actually use something equivalent to `sort(x, key=lambda x:tolower(x) )`.

To give another example, say you have a list of vectors and you want to sort on the second value. You would use something like `sort(x, key = lamda x:x[2] )` in python, right? In R you'd have to apply a function to your list, and use that in the order command:

```
x <- list(x1=1:10,x2=10:1,x3=rep(5,10))
id <- order(sapply(x,function(i)i[3]))
x[id]
```

**General method**

In R, you construct the key and use the order of that key as indices for the original object. The `order` function gives you an easy interface to sort on multiple keys at once. This allows you to construct the most complex sorting keys.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But what if the key I want  is some function, can I do it like a lambda expression in Python ?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at these [python key sort](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions) examples it seems that there are two thing that you might want a key for in R.

Firstly, applying a function to each element of the vector to be sorted.

```
x <- c("clementine", "APPLE", "Banana")
```

In R, you would just nest the function calls.

So rather than

```
sort(x, key = tolower)
```

you would just write

```
sort(tolower(x))
```

The other case is for sorting data frames by a particular column.

```
dfr <- data.frame(x = c(1, 4, 2, 5, 3), y = letters[c(5, 2, 1, 4, 3)])
```

Rather than

```
sort(dfr, key = function(row) row[2])
```

you would write

```
o <- with(dfr, order(y))
dfr[o,]
```

Comment: as for the first case you mentioned, how can I use the sorted lower case results to dertermin the order of the original vector ? After all it's the order of the original vector that matters to me.

Comment: @Spirit Zhang Look at `?order`

Answer (score 1):

The `sort` function would return the vector elements by default in ascending order, but leaves out any NA's. The `order` function returns a numeric vector with unique elements specifying the positions of elements in ascending sequence, leaving the NA's at the end. Many times user choose the `order` function for "sorting" dataframes and vectors because the lengths are preserved.

```
 temp=sample(1:10, 15, replace=TRUE)
 temp[c(3,12)] <- NA
 sort(temp)
# [1]  2  3  3  4  6  7  7  7  8  9  9 10 10
 order(temp)
# [1] 15  2 14  4 13  7  8 10 11  1  6  5  9  3 12
 temp
# [1]  9  3 NA  4 10  9  7  7 10  7  8 NA  6  3  2
 temp[ order(temp) ]
# [1]  2  3  3  4  6  7  7  7  8  9  9 10 10 NA NA
```

To modify the default numeric or alphabetic collation order one would wrap functions around the argument inside order which may be a multiple level sort if there are multiple arguments passed.